# Does computed `goto` respect C++ object lifetime?

Tags: c++, gcc, goto, raii

Regular `goto` in C++ respects object lifetime - that is using `goto` to jump out of a block will run the destructors for the appropriate local variables.

```
start:
NonTrivial object;
if (again()) goto start;  // will call object.~NonTrivial()
```

Is the same true when using the [Labels as Values](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html#Labels-as-Values) extension?

```
start:
NonTrivial object;
goto *(again() ? &&start : &&end);
end:
```

GCC happily accepts this code, but seems to ignore any effect `goto` might have on `object`'s lifetime. Clang complains:

```
error: cannot jump from this indirect goto statement to one of its possible targets
note: possible target of indirect goto statement
note: jump exits scope of variable with non-trivial destructor
```

Look for calls to `NonTrivial()` and `~NonTrivial()` in [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/sF66qG).

Which compiler behaves correctly? Is it even possible, in general, to support this kind of indirect branching and also correctly manage object lifetime and RAII?

Comment: "Which compiler behaves correctly" when employing an extension is a moot question. What authority can possibly answer that?

Comment: You should NOT use `goto`: https://xkcd.com/292/

Comment: @Superlokkus: yeah, that's a well founded argument against goto.

Comment: "Is it even possible, in general, to support this kind of indirect branching and also correctly manage object lifetime and RAII". It is possible to do, but in general, it would need a very large effort from the compiler writers, so it is unlikely to happen in the future (handling certain cases is easy, but the general case is hard, it needs code introspection).

Comment: @Superlokkus um in my memory I had confused the velociraptor being caused by UB not by goto, lots of bad dreams just due to a misunderstanding of a comic...

Comment: @idclev463035818 As I stated in my answer, I think this actually IS UB.

Comment: @Superlokkus that should read "You should NOT use `goto` **carelessly**".

Comment: Woops I just realized I read the C not the C++ standard. There is guaranteed. Sorry my fault.

Comment: Posting my answer as comment, because I noticed that I misread the question and that my answer is not actually answering the relevant part, really: Constructed objects with automatic storage duration are *always* destroyed when their scope is exited. It doesn't matter whether the exit is via goto. See e.g. [\[stmt.jump\]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/stmt.stmt#stmt.jump-2) of the C++17 standard (draft N4659). This says nothing about non-standard compiler extensions, though.

Comment: Note that clang complains about "non trivial destructor". See e.g. https://godbolt.org/z/6DFB_8

Comment: @Bob__ If you make the object trivial, then of course my question becomes much less interesting. I'm interested specifically in cases where the objects are not trivial. Real code where I might use such `goto`s involves deeply nested loops with `lock_guard`s and `unique_ptr`s.

Answer (score 1):

> Which compiler behaves correctly?

Since we are talking about language extension by GCC, we cannot use C++ standard for the judgement. But it is reasonable to expect that the compiler will call here destructor automatically the same number of times as constructor, or refuse to compile as Clang.

> Is it even possible, in general, to support this kind of indirect branching and also correctly manage object lifetime and RAII?

Probably yes, since GCC bug for this is reported and not closed yet: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=37722